# Como definir um atributo com valor fixo no ASP.Net MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Eu tenho uma classe usuário que possui o atributo `permissão`, que deve ser sempre 1. Onde e como eu faria pra fixar esse valor? Na pasta `models`, `controller` ou na própria `view` de cadastro?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No Model, mais especificamente no construtor:

```
public class Usuario
{
    ...
    public int Permissao { get; set; }

    public Usuario() {
        Permissao = 1;
    }
}
```

Para impedir a modificação do valor (propriedade somente leitura), você pode fazer da seguinte forma:

```
public class Usuario
{
    ...
    public int Permissao { get { return 1; } }
}
```

Para evitar que o valor seja mapeado no Entity Framework (caso esteja usando), use [`[NotMapped]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.schema.notmappedattribute(v=vs.118).aspx):

```
public class Usuario
{
    ...
    [NotMapped]
    public int Permissao { get { return 1; } }
}
```

Comment: Obrigado! Irei testar quando chegar em casa. Tinha tentado fazer na view,  mas não deu certo. Posso dizer então que classes de validação e atributos fixos devem ser feitos na pasta models? Ex. Uma classe para validar cpf

Comment: Sim, toda e qualquer informação de validação precisa ficar no *Model*. As validações devem ser feitas ou fazendo a classe implementar `IValidatableObject` ou usando atributos de validação.

Answer (score 0):

eu usaria:

```
public class Usuario
{
...
 public const int Permissao = 1;
}
```

se ele sempre for apenas um número sem regras, sem validações sem nada, então faz todo o sentido ser uma constante e pronto :)

Comment: No contexto do MVC, isto é fora do padrão, por mais que funcione.

Comment: sim você tem razão, mas ainda assim preferiria dessa forma, uma vez que de uma forma elegante eu não colocaria nenhuma das duas formas na minha classe de domínio.